# Error JIT vs2013

Tags: c#, mysql

Hola buenos días a todos, tengo un problema gigante, al tratar de correr mi aplicativo, c# y mysql, hecho con vs2013 en otra computadora, me lanza una ventana de error (excepción no controlada), en mi pc funciona bien pero en las otras dos nada... Probé instalando. Net framework, las librería runtime y todo eso y me sigue apareciendo el error...

El código que aparece al final es el siguiente:

> ********** Depuración JIT **************
>
> Para habilitar la depuración Just In Time (JIT), el archivo de configuración de esta aplicación o
> equipo (machine.config) debe tener el valor jitDebugging establecido
> en la sección system.windows.forms. La aplicación también se debe
> compilar con la depuración habilitada

Y el texto del error es este

> *********** Texto de la excepción **************
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como
> instancia de un objeto.    en
> CapaPresentacion.frmIngreso.btnIngresar_Click(Object sender, EventArgs
> e) en c:\Users\Nikos25\Desktop\PROYECTO CENTRO MEDICO
> CHILHUE\Software\sisGestion\CapaPresentacion\frmIngreso.cs:línea 58
> en System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    en
> System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    en
> System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    en
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
> button, Int32 clicks)    en
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    en
> System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    en
> System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    en
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
> en System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
> m)    en System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
> msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Al momento de compilar en el visual studio 2013 lo hace en modo release, no se si eso influirá en algo?

Saludos a todos y gracias anticipadas

Comment: Me temo que ese error no nos dice nada, simplemente parece que te está lanzando una excepción no controlada, pero sin poder ver detalles de que excepción, no podemos hacer mucho :)

Comment: Estimado gracias, añadí el texto del error

Comment: Esto es otra cosa. El error es evidente: un `nullreferencexception` en tu formulario `frmIngreso` en el click de `btnIngresar`. Tienes que revisar que haces en ese método (es posible que accedas a una base de datos a la que no tienes acceso desde las otras maquinas?)

Comment: En mi pc funciona bien, cuando copio la carpeta del proyecto al pc cliente, en esa maquina tengo instalado wamp, tengo la base de datos creada e importada, por lo cual no se cual podría ser el error, o hay que hacer algún adicional al copiar el directorio del proyecto a otra computadora?

Comment: Me doy cuenta que el log del error me muestra las rutas de mi computadora, siendo que la ejecución está en una computadora completamente diferente,